# Comprehensive list of American English words

Tags: dictionary, game-development

Is there a comprehensive list of American English words that omits swear words, jargon, and latin scientific words?

Comment: Here's one [freely available source](http://www.gwicks.net/dictionaries.htm).  You can start with one of the English lists and add and delete words to suit your needs.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.